# after session1.close(), session2 getting objects from cache in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I have heard that after **session.close()** , **the objects are in  this session will be removed from cache.**

If 'yes'
then why 'session2' object retrieving object from cache?

I am closing 'session1' when I'm fetching data first time(query executing) and data will be stored in cache(default first level cache), RIGHT !
But, after creating 'session2' object, I'm still able to retrieve particular object(no query is executing), means it is taking object from cache !
....**Why ?**

In image, I have paste my code
[Image : my java files, table, persistent class, output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOlXd.png)

Comment: how you came to conclusion that it is the same object which you fetched in previous session????

Comment: Because there  is no query executing for  my second session's object (Object o = session2.load(Pojo_class.class,1) )...Thats why I thought it is retrieving from same object that I have retrieved from first session's object (Criteria c = session1.createCriteria(Pojo_class.class); c.add(Restrictions.eq("id",1);  Am I wrong about same object for session2 ?

Comment: Check if the reference of the object you are retrieving are same or not. It would not be same as per the specification. Also can you share the hibernate configuration you have created . Is second level cache or query cache is enabled or not???

Comment: No. I haven't enabled any cache  in my configuration file!.......

Answer (score 0):

There are cache leves in Hibernate that you need to understand.

> First-level cache:
>
> The first-level cache is the Session cache and is a mandatory cache
>   through which all requests must pass. The Session object keeps an
>   object under its own power before committing it to the database.
>
> Second-level cache:
>
> Second level cache is an optional cache and first-level cache will
>   always be consulted before any attempt is made to locate an object in
>   the second-level cache. The second-level cache can be configured on a
>   per-class and per-collection basis and mainly responsible for caching
>   objects across sessions.
>
> Query-level cache:
>
> Hibernate also implements a cache for query resultsets that integrates
>   closely with the second-level cache.

All is quoted from here [Cache Hibernate Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm). So in short the First Level of cache of that Session is removed. But that doesn't mean that the other Session Cache or the Level 2 cache need to be removed, because has his own Cache. Hope it helped you.